# Getting Selected Values of Picklist RecordType

Tags: apex, picklist, record-type

Currently I am able to get all the values that are for a picklist. But I was wondering if it's possible to get just the selected values of a picklist for a RecordType using Apex? screenshot below:

[image]

Current snippet:

```
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues;
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.PicklistField__c.getDescribe();
picklistValues = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
```

Comment: This may or may not be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). For example, if your purpose is to render a picklist in Visualforce, it's usually sufficient to just set the RecordTypeId field on the related object, and then use apex:inputField; no Apex would be needed. Otherwise, this question is probably a duplicate. Have you tried [searching for this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=apex+recordtype+picklist)?

Comment: @sfdcfox, in this case the picklist is not inside Visualforce. In the Screenshot the picklist is in Accounts -> Record Type -> Select a Record Type -> Edit a Picklist Available for Editing.

Comment: I understand that the screenshot came from Setup, but it doesn't get back to the root of the problem. What do you intend to do with this information? Why do you need to know the available picklist values for a particular record type?